# Passing $(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER) to a parameter while using 3D Touch quick actions

Tags: ios, swift, 3dtouch

While using 3D Touch quick actions, $(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER) is used while setting up static quick actions. Is there a way to pass $(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER) to a variable/constant, such that any change in it is reflected while checking for the same in AppDelegate.swift?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8fIs.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

Swift

`let bundleIdentifier = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier`

Objective-c

```
NSString *bundleIdentifier = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
```